# Transforming an Observable<Object[]> into an Object[] inside component files

Tags: angular, ngrx

I know you can use pipes inside views to do that, but I have no idea how to do it inside a component file.

```
  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    this.posts$.subscribe((posts) => {
      console.log(posts); //This is the array of posts, not an observable
      moveItemInArray(this.posts, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
      this.postService.sortBoards(this.posts);
    });
  }
```

Do I really have to subscribe to get it every time? It goes against the "do not repeat yourself" principle. I am inside the app.component.ts file and I don't want to do a this.posts$.subscribe to extract posts every time I use it in one of the component functions (I have 5 functions that needs posts instead of posts$).

Answer (score 0):

If posts are static data then don't make it as Observable.
If this is not the case then you can get data from Observable from different methods like `subscribe, map, tap` and stored in a private variable. This variable can further be used in other functions.

```
private posts;
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    this.posts$.subscribe((posts) => {
      this.posts = posts;
      this.postService.sortBoards(this.posts);
    });
  }


 moveItemInArray(this.posts, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
```

Comment: I am getting posts from an effect. I am using NgRx and Effects, so it has to be an Observable. However, I need the posts to not be an observable so I can use the values. Also, subscribing to it means I need to unsubscribe it in the same function.

Comment: Yes, you should unsubscribe the Observable in `ngOnDestroy`.